# Dealing with disk space full in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a Django web application with postgresql 9.3.10 backend (sitting in a Linux OS). I ran into disk full error, such that even if I try to truncate a table, I get errors of the sort:

```
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/30137/33186048": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

I can't easily add more disk space to the server, nor can I delete stuff on this VM. However there are several tables that are candidates for truncation, but seems I can't truncate them now either.

Can anyone give me advice on what I can do here? This is hitting my production server hard, and I'm a bit of an accidental DBA here, so totally stumped.

Comment: You can reclaim some space if you can (temporarily) drop an index... truncate tables and then recreate it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because PostgreSQL must write WAL before making any changes to tables, it needs free disk space in order to delete things and release more disk space.

If you let the disk fill up, you can't recover from within PostgreSQL. Even `TRUNCATE` still has to write to WAL.

So you *must* free some space on the volume, or expand the volume. If your PostgreSQL log files are in `pg_log` in the data directory, you can safely remove some of those and restart Pg.

Do *not* delete `pg_xlog` or `pg_clog`. These are not server error logs, they're critical parts of the database, the transaction log and commit log.

Comment: Why does `TRUNCATE` have to write to wal, and what does that entry in WAL look like?

Comment: *"truncate does not log the full data, only the fact
that a truncate happened.  In order to be able to roll it back, the
underlying file is kept around until transaction commit."* [source](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20100211233013.GK3145%40alvh.no-ip.org So truncate's entry in wall is super small. mere bytes. If that was the entirety of the space load needed, you could probably get it by `rm -rf /tmp/*` or deleting your vimrc.

Comment: @EvanCarroll `rm -rf /tmp/*` ... that can delete things you might want too, such as application sockets etc. Better to be more selective. As for space needed, you're right, it's minimal - an 8k empty table + a few kb of WAL entries for the truncate, xid allocation, commit record, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A few more ideas on freeing up disk space in an emergency:

---

- If possible, prevent *new* client connections from being made.

---

- If possible, cancel non-critical running commands (`SELECT`, `COPY IN`, `COPY OUT`, `CREATE INDEX`, ...): not guaranteed to help, but may in some cases.

  1. Use `Pg_Cancel_Backend(<PID>)` if you already have a privileged session open, or just `kill -s INT -- <PID>` otherwise.

---

- If possible, disconnect non-critical sessions, whether idle or active; again, not guaranteed to help, but may in some cases.

  1. Use `Pg_Terminate_Backend(<PID>)` if you already have a privileged session open, or just `kill -s TERM -- <PID>` otherwise.

---

- If using `pg_prewarm` module:

  1. Run `SET pg_prewarm.autoprewarm_interval = 0`, if you already have a privileged session open.
  2. `rm -f <PGDATA>/autoprewarm.blocks`

---

- If using `pg_stat_statements` module, and have a privileged session open:

  1. Run `SELECT Pg_Stat_Statements_Reset()`.

---

- If have a privileged session open:

  1. Run `SELECT Pg_Stat_Reset()`.

---

- If possible, drop indexes on user data which are big enough to matter, and can definitely be rebuilt from just the table rows; start with the largest.

---

---

*(Just to be clear: these are all **temporary** measures, not long-term or even short-term solutions!)*